# Store all odd numbers between -6 and 38 into an array

Tags: java, equation

I'm doing some Java exercises, and this was one of them. I did this:

```
int odds[] = new int[22];

int storedNo = -5;

for (int i = 0; i < odds.length; i++) {
    odds[i] = storedNo;
    storedNo += 2;
}
```

Which works. But, I looked at the answer and it said to do this:

```
int[] odds = new int[22];

for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    odds[i] = i * 2 - 5;
}
```

My question is, how did they arrive at that answer?, specifically the `i * 2 - 5` part? I don't get how to think of the math to get that answer.

Comment: What is the first odd number that you are storing in the array?  What is the difference between consecutive odd numbers?  The answers have to do with math and not Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to think about it is that it evaluates the equation `y = 2x - 5` for integer values `x in [0, 21]`.

[image]

How did they arrive at this solution? One way is to look at the first and last points. We know the first odd number is at `x = 0`, `y = -5` and the last is at `x = 21`, `y = 37`. Two points is sufficient to solve for a linear equation `y = mx + b`:

From the first point we have

```
(-5) = m(0) + b
=> b = -5
```

From the second point we have

```
(37) = m(21) + b
=> 37 = 21m - 5
=> 21m = 42
=> m = 2
```

Thus our solution is `y = 2x - 5`. This also follows the intuitive observation that successive odd numbers have a difference of 2, and the y-intercept of the line should be the smallest number.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the math to see how it works. The first odd number you have is -5, so doing i*2 - 5 gives you -5 to start out when your loop variable is 0. When i increases by 1 on each loop iteration, you're going to have a result that's 2 greater than the previous.

0 * 2 - 5 = -5

1 * 2 - 5 = -3

2 * 2 - 5 = -1

...

21 * 2  -5 = 37